# Tabs with CSS only using checkbox id to be contained in target id

Tags: css, tabs

I would like to achieve some CSS functionality of tabs. I have following code (part):

```
array.map((name,index) => (
  '<input type="radio" 
     name="tabset" 
     id="tab'+index+'" 
   checked>
   <label for="tab'+index+'" class="tab-name">name</label>')) + 
  '<div class="tab-panels">' +
     array.map((name,index) => (
       '<div class="tab-panels">' +
       '<section id="tab'+index+'-content" class="tab-panel">text</section></div>'));
```

Now i have statically in css something like this

```css
.tab-panel {
  display: none;
}

.tabset > #tab0:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab0-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab1:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab1-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab2:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab2-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab3:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab3-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab4:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab4-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab5:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab5-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab6:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab6-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab7:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab7-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab8:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab8-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab9:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab9-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab10:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab10-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab11:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab11-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab12:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab12-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab13:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab13-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab14:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab14-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab15:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab15-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab16:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab16-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab17:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab17-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab18:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab18-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab19:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab19-content.tab-panel,
.tabset > #tab20:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab20-content.tab-panel {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is clear that it will work aligned with CSS definitions (up to 20)

Isn't there by any chance some CSS for this? like

```css
.tabset > #tab$:checked ~ .tab-panels > #tab$-content.tab-panel {
```

thanks

Comment: Not as you seem to describe... there isn't. You would need Javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you change the layout of your html, you can give the input a class and simplify your css to just use one line.

Move your radio input to be directly before the panel it is showing (it doesn't need to be above the labels) then you can use the [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator):

```css
.tab-panel,
.tab-input {
  display: none;
}

.tab-input:checked+.tab-panel {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="tab1" class="tab-name">tab 1</label>
<label for="tab2" class="tab-name">tab 2</label>
<label for="tab3" class="tab-name">tab 3</label>
<div class="tab-panels">
  <input type="radio" name="panel-toggle" class="tab-input" id="tab1" checked>
  <div class="tab-panel">tab 1</div>
  <input type="radio" name="panel-toggle" class="tab-input" id="tab2">
  <div class="tab-panel">tab 2</div>
  <input type="radio" name="panel-toggle" class="tab-input" id="tab3">
  <div class="tab-panel">tab 3</div>
</div>
```